# Handle $_SESSION, stored in a database table, when the user clear browser datas

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a little question about "how can i handle user when they are online" series...

**The intro** : I use MySQL for saving the online users, when they are logged of course, and everything works great.. when they logout i delete the row in "online_users" table.

**The problem** : When someone clear the browser data the $_SESSION[] results empty and the user is not logged in, of course, **BUT** in my Database i'm still having the row for that user, and it means that for my datase he is online .. and that is not good you know.

**First solution** : I decide to check, every time someone made a login, if there's a row, with the userID in "online_user", to make an Update QUERY, else i do an Insert QUERY.

But i think this is not the best solution, because it means that i have some garbage row in "online_users" until they remake the login...

Can some one tell me if there's another great solution for this problem?

I think i can use HTML5 with localstorage but not every browser support it...

What should i do in this case?

Thanks for every answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been answered for million times: have a last activity field in your online users table and delete the rows with last activity older than 15 minutes ago

Comment: Thank you :) i really forget it :)